# Get mode of _value column in Flux query

Tags: influxdb, flux, influxdb-2, influxql, flux-influxdb

How to get mode of column values where column is either true or false (boolean) ?

```
from(bucket: "monitor")
                      |> range(start: 0)
                      |> filter(
                          fn: (r) =>
                              r._measurement == "weather_status" and r._field == "is_good"
                                  and
                                  r.location_id == "69",
                      )
                      |> aggregateWindow(every: 1h, fn: mode, column: "_value")
```

Current query is returning null at some time points.

> I tried giving createEmpty: false inside aggregateWindow. But it is not completely useful. I have observed that if every record in a 1h interval is either true or false, it is returning as null.